# Clear cache of all installed applications

Tags: java, android, caching, delete-file

How can I do this. I know others apps that are doing the same thing without require root permission and there is a permission `CLEAR_APP_CACHE`.

Is there an api for that or method?

How can I access path of every application cache directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
File[] cacheFiles = new File("/data/data").listFiles();
for(int i = 0; i < cacheFiles.length; i++){
    cacheFiles[i].delete();
}
```

"/data/data"  -  System cache dir/

Comment: i think it will delete my app cache not others app

Comment: Yes. I didn't understan your question correctly. Sorry for my english.